How to handle success and failure in springboot for basic auth?
I need to add some custom logic like using a service to log my failed attempts or reset my failed attempts on successfull login. How do I do this with httpBasic ? So I need a failure handler and success handler for httpBasic().
Currently I am trying to add custom filter like this
Spring security config
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SpringSecurityConfig {
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("customAuthenticationEntryPoint")
    AuthenticationEntryPoint authEntryPoint;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("customBasicAuthFilter")
    BasicAuthenticationFilter customBasicAuthFilter;

    @Bean
    @Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE + 5)
    public SecurityFilterChain initSetupSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http
                .securityMatcher(AntPathRequestMatcher.antMatcher("/init-setup/**"))
                .authorizeHttpRequests(authorizeRequests  ->
                        authorizeRequests
                                .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/init-setup/otp").permitAll()
                                .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/init-setup/default-client-credentials").authenticated()
                                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                )
                .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .sessionManagement(sessionManagement ->
                        sessionManagement.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
//                .httpBasic(basic -> basic.authenticationEntryPoint(authEntryPoint)) // custom authentication entry point
                .addFilterAt(customBasicAuthFilter, BasicAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .exceptionHandling(Customizer.withDefaults());
        return http.build();
    }
}

customBasicAuthFilter
@Component("customAuthenticationFilter")
public class CustomBasicAuthFilter extends BasicAuthenticationFilter {

    @Autowired
    public CustomBasicAuthFilter(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) {
        super(authenticationManager);
    }

    protected void onSuccessfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
                                              Authentication authResult) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("SUCCESS::");
    }

    protected void onUnsuccessfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
                                                AuthenticationException failed) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("FAILS::");
    }

}

The application isn't starting and is throwing this error
Parameter 0 of constructor in com.shabodi.laas.config.CustomBasicAuthFilter required a bean of type 'org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager' that could not be found.

Consider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager' in your configuration.


This question is similar to: Consider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager' in your configuration. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Try adding these 2 annotations to the CustomBasicAuthFilter class.


Hope that helps.

